# How to run groovy in Android env?

Tags: android, groovy

I'm trying to run groovy program in Android. I use:

```
new GroovyShell(aBinding).evaluate(code)
```

to run the program, where `code` is the Groovy code. When I run this program with `code` as:

```
println "Hello"
```

I'm getting the error saying:

```
can't load this type of class file

08-16 09:10:48.502  31488-31488/com.groovy.console W/System.err﹕ org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
08-16 09:10:48.502  31488-31488/com.groovy.console W/System.err﹕ General error during class generation: can't load this type of class file
08-16 09:10:48.503  31488-31488/com.groovy.console W/System.err﹕ [ 08-16 09:10:48.503 31488:0x7b00 W/System.err ]
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
08-16 09:10:48.503  31488-31488/com.groovy.console W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(Native Method)
08-16 09:10:48.503  31488-31488/com.groovy.console W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:292)
```

where I'm making mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the grooid groovy library? http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/06/grooid.html

Comment: Yes I'm using that lib.

Comment: Where I'm making the mistake? Is it a bug in that andorid groovy plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The bytecode of the compiled script needs to be converted in to DEX bytecode before executed on Android.

There is a grooidshell implementation doing exactly this:

https://github.com/melix/grooidshell-example